# How to create a new row that contains Aggregate of a field in Kendo UI grid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid, I am trying to trying to create a header, that takes up the entire row and just says "SUM : 13"

I have a kendo Grid, that returns data, the sum of one of these columns is = 13, and store it so I can change a grid's title to:
"Results: 13"

How can I do this?
I have declared a variable outside of that scope to hold that sum.
I want to then... iterate through this, storing the data in that variable and
afterwards, call a function to update the header title?

I cannot use headerGroup or footerDetail templates, as i need the data to be on the top, and headerGroup adds unnecessary information inside the grid.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Toolbar template](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/toolbar-template)?

Comment: Im looking into it but maybe im too dumb to understand how this applies... I'll comment back if I figure it out, but greatly appreciate the comment.

Comment: The Toolbar template will appear at the top of your grid and since it's just a template, you can add different controls that you want to it.

Comment: is the aggregate that I want a control? sorry I'mma pleb.

Comment: also if this all works out, you can paste it as an answer instead of a comment and I'll mark it as the answer.  :P good for your score xD